# Is there away to change the internal [[Class]] property of a JavaScript Object?

Tags: javascript

Suppose that I have created a function constructor such as

```
    function Bar(){
    }
    var obj = new Bar();
```

Is there away to make `Object.prototype.toString.call(obj)` return something like `[object Date]` ?

Comment: Are you looking for this? `obj.constructor.name`

Comment: Are you trying to call `new Date()` using `new Bar()` ?

Comment: Why would you want to do that?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[ECMAScript5](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-8.6.2) doesn't provide any way to modify [[Class]]:

> This specification defines no ECMAScript language operators or
>   built-in functions that permit a program to modify an object’s
>   [[Class]] or [[Prototype]] internal properties or to change the value
>   of [[Extensible]] from false to true. Implementation specific
>   extensions that modify [[Class]], [[Prototype]] or [[Extensible]] must
>   not violate the invariants defined in the preceding paragraph.

ECMAScript6 removed the [[Class]] internal slot, but you can use the @@toStringTag [Well-Known Symbol](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-well-known-symbols):

> - Specification Name
>     @@toStringTag
> - [[Description]]
>     `"Symbol.toStringTag"`
> - Value and Purpose
>     A String valued property that is used in the creation of the default string description of an object. Accessed by the built-in method [`Object.prototype.toString`](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-object.prototype.tostring).

```
Bar.prototype[Symbol.toStringTag] = 'Date';
Object.prototype.toString.call(new Bar()); // "[object Date]"
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure that when ES6 is an option, `class Bar extends Date` is the better approach for whatever OP is trying to do :-)

Comment: @Bergi True, probably that's what OP wants. Just changing the result of `{}.toString` doesn't seem much useful.

Comment: unfortunately, both 'Symbol.toStringTag' & 'extends' are not options in this case.

Comment: If you can't use ES6 features, you won't be able to do it with ES5 alone, unless your implementation provides a extension to do it.

Comment: @Bergi Why couldn't he do that without ES6 ?

Comment: @Taurus Because there is no `class` syntax in ES5 :-)

Comment: @Bergi What about `Foo.prototype = Object.create(Date.prototype)` ? However, I have to admit that I know little more than a rock when ES6 is concerned, so.

Comment: @Taurus No, that does not work, as it does not cause `Foo` to create (native) `Date` instances

Comment: @Bergi How so ? Doesn't the resulting object inherit all of `Date.prototype`'s methods ?

Comment: @Taurus Yes, but it's still not a native `Date` object with the respective internal slots. Which is what matters here.

Answer (score 0):

If you want data object - create it, then you can just extend it for your own purposes, but the overall idea 'smells'.

```
            Bar.prototype.test = function () {
                return 'test';
            };
            function Bar(){
                var resultObject = new Date();
                Object.setPrototypeOf(resultObject, Object.assign(Object.create(Date.prototype), Bar.prototype));
                return resultObject;
            }
            var obj = new Bar();
            obj.test() === 'test';

            Object.prototype.toString.call(obj) === '[object Date]'
```