# How to mimic arrays in javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, mocking

I'd like to understand how Arrays are specified and built.

I'm mixing arrays with extra methods and trying to pass in `Array.isArray()`. I can pass `instanceof` and Poly-filled `isArray`

```js
var protoOfArray = Object.getPrototypeOf([])

var tools4Arrays = Object.defineProperty(
  Object.create(protoOfArray),
  'sum', {
    'value': function sum() {
      return this.reduce((a, b) => a + b, 0)
    }
  }
)
tools4Arrays[Symbol.toStringTag] = 'Array'

var fakeArray = Object.defineProperty(
  Object.create(
    tools4Arrays
  ),
  'length', {
    'value': 0,
    'writable': true
  }
)

console.log(`fakeArray instanceof Array: ${fakeArray instanceof Array}`)
console.log(`polyfill.isArray(fakeArray): ${Object.prototype.toString.call(fakeArray) === '[object Array]'}`)
console.log(`Array.isArray(fakeArray): ${Array.isArray(fakeArray)}`)
```

If I use: `fakeArray = Object.setPrototypeOf([], tools4Arrays)` the last log is true too.

What else separates arrays of objects?
Can I mock it?

Comment: Do you mean what else separates arrays **from** objects? Or are you asking something specifically regarding arrays containing objects?

Comment: @joe: It's not about an array of objects. Can I build an array editing from an object? Whats transformations need to construct an array over regulars object?
My fakeArray don't pass Array.isArray(). How do I get closer? Are this transitions possible? Or are array irreducible from objects?

Answer (score 1):

In order to mimic an Array you'd have to pass the internals of `isArray` which has the following checks (defined [here](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.4.3.2)):

> 1. If Type(arg) is not Object, return false.
> 2. If the value of the [[Class]] internal property of arg is "Array", then return true.
> 3. Return false.

The `Type` here appears to be the same as `instanceof`, which you've been able to pass just fine. However, the second step points at some internal `[[Class]]` property, which I'm not sure we have write access to.

Comment: its give me some paths to search:[change class](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35900626/10871623) [Symbol.species](https://www.keithcirkel.co.uk/metaprogramming-in-es6-symbols/)

Comment: [es9 isArray](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/9.0/index.html#sec-isarray) talks about exotics and proxy arrays I did not even know.

Answer (score 0):

I got what I needed, but I still do not have the answer... A fake array is [very slower](https://jsperf.com/push-fake-array/1) than a regular array, maybe have many internal optimizations and mimic it will lose that speed.

[subclass an array without a class](https://davidtang.io/2017/09/21/subclassing-arrays-in-es2015.html#can-you-subclass-an-array-without-a-class)

my [use case](https://github.com/itacirgabral/blog/blob/master/6/final.html)