# What is the proper terminology for a JavaScript array that includes non-numeric keys?

Tags: javascript, arrays, associative-array, terminology

I'm looking for an answer other than "bad practice".

> PLEASE, this is a question about TERMINOLOGY only! This is NOT a question about alternative ways this could be done, why it's better to use an object or Map instead of an array, why the length property of the array and the number of keys are different, etc.

The terminology "associative array" seems to typically be used for an object declared with curly braces, but then accessed with square brackets, like this:

```
const a = {'not-a-proper-identifier': 'foo'};
a['not-a-proper-identifier'] // returns 'foo'
```

But you can do this:

```
const a = [1, 2, 3];
a['foo'] = 'bar';
a['foo']; // Yep, 'bar' comes back.
console.log(a); // Output (at least from Chrome) is [1, 2, 3, foo: "bar"]
Array.isArray(a); // This is still true
a.length; // 3
Object.keys(a).length; // 4
JSON.stringify(a); // Only returns [1,2,3], 'foo' disappears.
[1, 2, 3, foo: "bar"] // Syntax error! The console representation isn't proper JavaScript.
```

So, if you were to do this with an array, is there something special to call this kind of array?

Why do I ask?

NOT because I particularly want to use this data structure myself, but because I would like to be able to support serializing and deserializing such an array, if and when encountered, for a variation on JSON that I'm working on, [JSON-Z](https://github.com/kshetline/json-z), a fork off the [JSON5](https://github.com/json5/json5) project.

And if I'm going to support it, it would be nice to know what terminology use when referring to an array like this.

Comment: I don't think there's a common definition, because such a thing is almost never done (because it's a bad idea)

Comment: "Associative array" is a term from PHP programming, in JavaScript, these are just called objects

Comment: Array with non-numeric keys?

Comment: I'll just repeat what I said the last time you posted this question - I'll call this "misusing arrays" but I don't think there is any common term for it.

Comment: [Array](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array) is nothing but an object comes with an extra box of candies `(isArray, .map, .reduce, etc)`. you can have non-numeric keys with arrays because actually its an object but it's not what arrays are meant to be used as.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's take it as written that adding non-numeric keys to an array is not a good idea; the comments clearly agree on this and it's evident enough from the code example you've provided. The language struggles, on the surface, to handle this consistently.

The explanation of the code you've written is probably not necessary but I feel it's good to illustrate as clearly as possible why some of the surface inconsistencies exist in javascript so as to better understand how the language works.

Examining the example you provide:

```js
const a = [1, 2, 3];
```

`a` is an array, but arrays are objects in javascript.

```js
a['foo'] = 'bar';
```

You can set properties on objects.

```js
a['foo'];
```

This will indeed be `bar`; we're just accessing a property on an object

```js
console.log(a); // Output (at least from Chrome) is [1, 2, 3, foo: "bar"]
```

Chrome seems to have done an admirable job at interpreting how to log this to a console, it could alternatively just log this out as a standard object.

```js
Array.isArray(a); // This is still true
```

It is true; `Array.isArray` [checks the Class internal property in order to determine what is an array](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.4.3.2). [This answer indicates that this can't be changed.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35900626/5011469)

```js
a.length; // 3
```

Length is calculated as the max numeric key + 1

```js
JSON.stringify(a); // Only returns [1,2,3], 'foo' disappears.
```

Indeed - JSON cannot handle this kind of mixing of keys (as you probably know, considering you're working on a project to extend JSON) so it has to decide whether to parse the object as a json object, or a json array.

The console representation is really only as good a representation of the data being logged as is possible, and given the mixed nature of javascript objects - used for both arrays and dictionaries, effectively, it's hard to get a perfect representation of the data.

As to your actual question... I haven't been able to find a name for those object properties. I'd say the best description I could imagine is:

> Object properties which do not conform to standard javascript naming
>   syntax

This isn't particularly good but it seems that the actual answer to your question is simply **no, there isn't a name for these.**

Comment: "Object properties which do not conform to standard javascript naming syntax" isn't exactly pithy, but I suppose if being able to stuff non-numeric keys into an array (and negative and non-integer numeric keys too) is more of an accident than a design, there wouldn't need to be concise terminology for the concept.

Comment: @kshetline indeed - though I'm not entirely sure that it's an accident, just a quirk of javascript's design. I think the reason it isn't named is that it's basically an issue with how js is interpreted. A key can be any string, fair enough, but can you have _an_y string after a `.` and outside of quotes? No, not really, because how would that be interpreted? If I have `x = { 'a -b': 2 }`, I obviously can't access it as `x.a-b` because the interpreter won't know whether that `x['a-b'] or `x.a` minus `b`

Comment: I thank you for taking the time to discuss this politely. It seems a lot of people can't separate their reasonable objection to the idea of using a non-numeric key on an array (which I'm certainly not in favor of as a realistic practice!) from someone simply wanting to know if there's a concise way to refer to the concept.

Comment: Some people aren't in too much of a hurry to cast a down vote or make a snarky comment, however.

Answer (score -1):

It's just "object". `obj['foo']` is an equivalent of `obj.foo`.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object

Comment: OP is specifically asking for an *array*, Arrays *are* objects but are definitely described and handled differently often enough, thus saying "it's an object" is not really useful.

Comment: think of arrays as objects that have the key as the indices of the array, e.g. `['foo', 'bar']` ~ `{0: 'foo', 1: 'bar'}`

Comment: Yes, it's an object, but more specifically it's also an array according to `Array.isArray()`, which would not be true if the object were originally declared with curly braces. It serializes via JSON with square brackets too (albeit with the non-numeric keys missing), not curly braces.

Comment: @andymccullough but that's still not answering OP's question. An array that contains non-integer keys is NOT called "an object" usually and if anybody *does* call it that, then that would be misleading. For example, you can't iterate an object (as in, natively), but you can an array.

Comment: But that's exactly what it is: treating an array like a generic object. Sorry.

Comment: @mbojko so, if I told you "this function expects an object" you'd know that the object needs to have keys from, say, zero to five filled in *and* have the key `foo` set *and* have a `.length` property *and* support the iteration protocol?

Comment: 'Associative array' then

Comment: @andymccullough which is not a term used for this, either. It's the *wrong* term that comes from PHP and anybody who hears (or reads) "associative array" and knows JS would identify it as "object".

Comment: This discussion doesn't seem at all productive. I'm out.

Comment: Then it's nothing more than abusing JS's array implementation (and we're trying to figure a name out for it) by setting its underlying key to be a string rather than an integer. After all, it was a language designed in around 3 weeks... And by abuse, I mean - 'Arrays cannot use strings as element indexes (as in an associative array) but must use integers. Setting or accessing via non-integers using bracket notation (or dot notation) will not set or retrieve an element from the array list itself, but will set or access a variable associated with that array's object property collection. '

Comment: @mbojko you still posted an answer that does not answer the question.